# JPA Select Count Distinct

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria

I need a relatively simple query, but JPA makes it kind of hard to create it.

The SQL variant would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS DistinctOrders FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID=7;
```

[Edit: OrderID is NOT the primary key. There can be more OrderId that are equals in the table]

I need to set the `CustomerID` with a variable that is passed to my method.

I found documentation on `CriteriaQuery` `distinct()` but I can't seem to wrap it all together.

This is what I have so far:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> c = cb.createQuery( Order.class );
Root<Order> order = c.from( Order.class );
Path<String> customerID = order.get( "customerID" );
c.where( cb.equal( customerID, theId ) );
```

Comment: JPQL? "SELECT COUNT(o.orderID) FROM Orders o WHERE o.customerID = :customerID GROUP BY o.orderID"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> c = cb.createQuery(Long.class);//the query returns a long, and not Orders
Root<Order> order = c.from( Order.class );
//c.select(cb.countDistinct(order));//and this is the code you were looking for
c.select(cb.countDistinct(order.get("orderID")));//for counting distinct fields other than the primary key
Path<String> customerID = order.get( "customerID" );
c.where( cb.equal( customerID, theId ) );
```

Comment: How does this that into account the 'OrderId'? I know it is a bit of a silly name, but there could be more fields in 'Order' with a similar 'OrderId'. I think the count will end up too high now?

Comment: If `OrderId` is the primary key in the `Order` table, than the resulting SQL query will take exactly that field. So: is OrderId the primary key in the table? Of course if you want you can check the generated/executed query (either switch on the logging in your JPA provider or check the logging on your DB level).

Comment: It is not. I created this example code because I cannot post real code. The table is more like 'OrderMutation' where there can be more than one 'OrderId'