# Get collection count instead of the collection in JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, criteria

Lets say I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Permission> permissions;
    // etc
    // other fields here
}
```

I want a to build a query using the Criteria API that filters these users and shows a list of people and among other info from the entity - how many roles does a person have.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);
// predicates here
```

However, this limits me to returning only a list of `Person` entities. I can always add a `@Transient` field to the entity, but this seems ugly since I might have many different queries and might end up with many such fields.

On the other hand - I cant use `HQL` and write the query since I want complex filtering and I would have to deal with appending and removing things from the `HQL` query.

My question, besides the one in the title of this post is this: how do I query the database using the Criteria API and return a non-entity (in case I want to filter the Person table but return only the number of roles, permissions, etc) and how do I do it for something very close to the actual entity (like the example with the role counter instead of the roles collection)?

**UPDATE**
Using Hibernate's projections I came up with this. But still don't know that to write in `TODO`. `Projections.count` doesn't work since it excpects some kind of grouping, and I don't seem to be able to find any examples in the `Hibernate` documentation.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Person.class);

if (id != null) {
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
}

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
projectionList.add(TODO, "rolesCount");
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14676881/785663)?

Comment: Or something like the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707529/jpa-select-count-distinct/19708805#19708805 ?

Comment: These two answers return a count/sum, which is only a part of what I need. I can always have multiple querries - for example one filtering the entities and one counting the roles and then mapping the rwo results, but I'm looking for a practical way to do these in one Criteria query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883887/in-jpa-2-using-a-criteriaquery-how-to-count-results

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().get().createQuery(Long.class);
query.select(builder.get().countDistinct(root));
```

works for me:)

Answer (score 0):

> how do I do it for something very close to the actual entity (like
>   the example with the role counter instead of the roles collection

You could make these values properties of your User entity by various means, for example using a Hibernate @Forumula property. This will issue an inline subquery on Entity load to get the count without touching the collection.

```
@Formula("select count(*) from roles where user_id = ?")
private int numberOfRoles;
```

Another (JPA compliant) option is to handle these calculated fields by creating a view at the database level and the mapping this to your User:

e.g.

```
@OneToOne
private UserData userData; //entity mapped to your view (works just like a table)

....

public int getNumberOfRoles(){
   return userData.getRoleCOunt();
```

or

by using @SecondaryTable to join this User data.

Comment: These are all workarounds. I'm looking for a general JPA-compliant way to achieve these queries with the help of the Criteria API. Also, what about the non-entity returning query?

Comment: Well if that's all you're looking for I imagine Projections and Constructor expressions are what you're after.